# AngularJS, PhoneGap, ionic, grunt difference between web and mobile

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, gruntjs, ionic-framework

Okay I am not sure what's going on...

I build a simple app using: "AngularJS, PhoneGap, ionic, grunt"...

After grunt:dist or grunt serve I see everything nicely working in the browser

BUT

when I try to run it with grunt ripple OR with grunt build + phonegap build android + phonegap run android I am able to see only the ionic header and no content... any idea what could be possible wrong? Because I have no idea what could causing it.

Is there something I need to take care when switching to mobile? or ?

The console is clean as well:

```
→ adb logcat | grep -i console
I/Web Console(28936): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing.     
Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only.:966
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhhhhhhhhh found an answer!!!

As [Eduardo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840531/using-angular-ui-router-with-phonegap?answertab=active#tab-top) mentioned there is a problem with the slash at the beginning of template path.

It should be:

```
templateUrl: "scripts/src/LandingPage/views/home.html",
```

Maybe someone will find it useful.

For more detailed explanation checkout Eduardo's answer.